# Treatment of the Damping term in pendulum equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, aerodynamics

I am confronted by two differing equations for a damped pendulum. I want to back out the drag coefficient at each point of a pendulum's motion. I have the velocity and the acceleration at each point.

In the pendulum equation  $\ddot{\theta}+ \frac{k}{m} \dot{\theta}+\frac{g}{l} \sin \theta=0$ if the damping term is substituted by the drag force then negative values are obtained for $C_{D}$. I was wondering if I could rewrite it as the following. $\ddot{\theta}-F_{d}+\frac{g}{l} \sin \theta=0$  where, $F_{d}=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2AC_{D}$

Comment: As currently written, your positive drag force $F_d$ **accelerates** the pendulum as it sweeps forward at the bottom of its arc, for example ($\ddot \theta=F_d>0$ at $\theta=0$, $v> 0$). Is that really what you want?

Comment: Possibly useful reference: Mungan and Lipscombe's "[Oscillations of a quadratically damped pendulum](https://www.usna.edu/Users/physics/mungan/_files/documents/Publications/EJP15.pdf)."

Comment: Thanks for the response. Essentially, I want to get the drag coefficient from the equation of motion. I now realize that the way I've written it isn't accurate.

Comment: Have you at least tried to solve the first equation?

Comment: I haven't actually looked at the numerical values as a result of the first equation, I'm just not sure what I should do.

Comment: Your first equation is where $F_d \propto v$, which is true for small speeds or movement in highly viscous media. It's worth solving (Wolfram alpha or Integration with an integrating factor) so you can at least have a look what the simpler case (compared to $F_d \propto v^2$) looks like...

Comment: So I have the experimental data which gives me the position, velocity and acceleration of the bob. Would I then be correct in saying $C_{D} = \frac{-2m(a+g\sin\theta)}{\rho A v |v|}$

Answer (score 1):

If we balance forces in the direction of motion and divide by $m$, we have

$$a+\frac{F_d}{m}+g\sin\theta=0,$$

where $a$ is acceleration, $F_d$ is a drag force, $m$ is mass, $g$ is the acceleration from gravity, and $\theta$ is the angle measured from the vertical.

If we then choose to model the drag as quadratic (an assumption we would be well advised to confirm), the drag force is $F_d=-\frac{1}{2}\rho v|v|C_dA$, where $\rho$ is the density of the surrounding fluid, $v$ is velocity, $C_d$ is the drag coefficient, and $A$ is the cross-sectional area.

If $a$, $v$, and $\theta$ are known, then we can estimate $C_d$ as

$$C_d=-\frac{2m(a+g\sin\theta)}{v|v|\rho A},$$

which it looks like you’ve successfully derived in the comments.

Comment: Pity that c$_d$ isn't constant at low speeds. Otherwise you are correct.